# LinQ OrderBy anonymous value

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

Following code is not working:

```
var x = from user in db.tblUsers
        select new
        {
            user.Id,
            user.FirstName,
            user.LastName,
            NumOfWins = SqlFactory.GetNumberOfWinsByUser(user.Id)
        };

TblBindingSource.DataSource = x.OrderByDescending(user => user.NumOfWins);
dataGridView1.DataSource = TblBindingSource.DataSource; //<-- fail here
```

Error:

> Method 'Int32 GetNumberOfWinsByUser(Int32)' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

I know that `SqlFactory.GetNumberOfWinsByUser(user.Id)` returns a good value. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try eager loading the result of your query using `ToList()` or `ToArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this kind of embedding of functions into Linq2SQL queries, provided your function (`GetNumberOfWinsByUser()` in your case) can itself be written as `Expression<Func<>>` type where the expression can be converted to SQL by the provider

This was devised by Tomáš Petříček and described on his blog:

http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx

It explains how you can defined an expression:

```
Expression<Func<Nwind.Product, decimal?>> calcPrice = 
  (p) => p.UnitPrice * 1.19m;
```

and then embed that into a Linq to SQL query:

```
var q = 
   from p in db.Products.ToExpandable()  
   where calcPrice.Expand(p) > 30.0m
   select new { 
     p.ProductName, 
     OriginalPrice = p.UnitPrice,
     ShopPrice = calcPrice.Expand(p) };
```

Using an extension method `ToExpandable()` that he created (the code is available for download).

This allows the entire query to be parsed into SQL and executed on the DB server without having to materialise any partial results sets into memory. It should be pretty efficient and can be made to handle very complex queries. I generally found that encapsulating the logic into expressions liek this led to simple code with good re-usability.

I used this extensively in a project and it works very well. You need to have a good grasp of expressions though.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error.  You are obviously using a linq providor such as entity framework that translates your linq into SQL.  It can't translate the method SqlFactory.GetNumberOfWinsByUser(user.Id) into a SQL statement.  If you want to use it you will have to do something like :

```
from user in db.tblUsers.ToList()
          select new { user.Id, user.FirstName, user.LastName, NumOfWins =     SqlFactory.GetNumberOfWinsByUser(user.Id) };
```

That will force it to fetch the data into memory first and then apply the transform in your select statement.

I suspect that the above is very inefficient but that is just a guess.

Comment: I try this but it returns an empty value

Comment: It is not doing any filtering, do you have any rows in your database table?

Comment: TblBindingSource.DataSource = db.tblUsers.Select(u => u); returns all table data ,  TblBindingSource.DataSource = db.tblUsers.ToList().Select(u => u); return empty rows

Comment: Note that you should use `AsEnumerable` to ensure that future LINQ calls to an IQueryable are evaluated as Linq-to-objects, rather than ToList, as it avoids eagerly evaluating the entire query.

Comment: @Servy The whole point of the call ToList() was to enumerate the collection and force it to get the data from the database.

Comment: @dsfdf dsf what linq providor are you using?  the 2 examples should fetch the same data it's just that the first would defer execution of the query until something tried to enumerate the collection.

Comment: @BenRobinson Which you don't need to do, you just need to ensure that the following `Select` call is implemented as Linq-to-objects and not interpreted by the query provider as a query, which `AsEnumerable` is *specifically designed to do*.  You don't need to get all of the data and pull it into memory, you just need to ensure that the remaining operations aren't interpreted by the query provider.

Comment: OK I'll take your word on that.